# How 'toString' get resolved here?

Tags: java, overriding

Below `interface I` implicitly has the public methods of `class Object` as abstract members. One of them is `toString()`

```
interface I{ 
   void test(int i);
   //implicitly has abstract members matching every public method of 'class Object'
   // one of them is toString()
}
```

Below `class W` inherits `class Object` public methods, one of them is `toString`,

```
class W implements I{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       I w = new W();
       w.toString();   //How toString() method is resolved here?
    }
}
```

As **both**, super interface(`I`) and super class(`Object`) of `class W` **have** `toString()` method,

How does `javac` resolve `w.toString()` at compile time? I learnt that `invokevirtual` instruction is used here.

How does jvm resolve `w.toString()` at runtime?

Comment: `interface` doesn't override anything from `Object`...

Comment: I don't see the problem here? An interface is not an abstract class, if that's your confusion, and a method defined in an interface never *overrides* a method in a class.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt When I say, `interface I { public int equals(Object obj); }` I get compiler error, the `return type is incompatible with Object.equals(obj)`. How do I understand this? Is it the reason that, any interface which has no super interface, implicilty has members matching every public method in `Object`? which is different from overrding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the method is invoked on an expression of type `I`, an interface type, the bytecode will contain an [`invokeinterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokeinterface) instruction for the corresponding method.

At runtime, the method invoked will be determined as such

> Let `C` be the class of `objectref`. The actual method to be invoked is
>   selected by the following lookup procedure:
>
> - If `C` contains a declaration for an instance method with the same name and descriptor as the resolved method, then it is the method to be invoked.
> - Otherwise, if `C` has a superclass, a search for a declaration of an instance method with the same name and descriptor as the resolved
>     method is performed, starting with the direct superclass of `C` and
>     continuing with the direct superclass of that class, and so forth,
>     until a match is found or no further superclasses exist. If a match is
>     found, then it is the method to be invoked.
> - Otherwise, if there is exactly one maximally-specific method (§5.4.3.3) in the superinterfaces of `C` that matches the resolved
>     method's name and descriptor and is not abstract, then it is the
>     method to be invoked.

In your case, `objectref` is a reference to an object of type `W`. `W` **does not** contain a declaration for an instance method with the same name and descriptor as the resolved method. We therefore check the superclass of `W`, `Object`. `Object` **does** have such a method. That method is therefore invoked.

Answer (score 1):

An `interface` doesn't override a method.

Also your class doesn't override the method `toString()`. You have to rewrite the method `toString()` to overerride it.

So simply it is called the implementation of `toString()` of  the superclass `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces don't override methods from any class. When you use the `toString()` method, the default `toString()` is executed from the `Object` class because your class `W` extends from `Object`. For more clarification, override the `toString()` method in your class `W`.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return "Yo, baby! M here!";
}
```

Then the output will be:

```
Yo, baby! M here!
```

Answer (score -2):

Interface doesn't have any super class not even the Object class e.g.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    Class cls = java.lang.Cloneable.class;
    Class sup = cls.getSuperclass(); // will return null
  }
}
```

Hence interface never override a method of an Object class.

> When an interface has no direct SuperInterface, it will create
>   abstract public method for  all those public methods present in the
>   Object class.